# Java design pattern for notifications

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a web based application which sends messages to a client from the server every time some action has been performed in the backend. Now, I'm writing a few tests to see if the messages that are being sent to the client are the expected messages. 
Each action, when executed, generates a certain message which is sent across to the client.
In my test, I've created a WebSocket client to listen to the server. Now when I perform certain action, I should check whether the expected message for this action is being sent.
Note that the server takes some time to send the message.

The following is just a pseudo code:

```
class ApplicationTest
    public void checkIfEventCreatedMsgIsSent() {
        Application.createNewEvent("Id101");
        // Wait till the application sends message to the client
        // And then check that the message sent is the correct one
        // if (expectedMessage == recievedMessageFromClient) {
        //   success();
        // }

    }

class Client
    public void readMessage(Message message) {
        // Received the new event message with Id101
        // Now this message should be sent to ApplicationTest.checkIfEventCreatedMsgIsSent and confirmed by it
    }
}
```

I get the message to the client and every thing is fine.

But I'm unable figure out how to notify `ApplicationTest` that a message has been received by the client and then verify. I tried implementing `Observer Design Pattern` here, but that just made more confused. 
How should I go about in implementing this and what kind of design pattern is best suited for such scenarios ?

Comment: What exactly confuse you in Observer pattern?

Comment: I think Observer Pattern will suite your problem.

Comment: I thought so too. But then I need `ApplicationTest` to somehow wait till the server sends a message and then get the client message and then compare. This is where it got confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-writing your class with few basic assumptions

We are storing a Map of values like 
`Map<String, Object> msg = new HashMap<String, Object>()` which will be loaded with `(EventId, EventDetailsObject).`
Above Map msg will be stored in ServletContext, it could alternatively be a persistent message on MQ or a value in db.
The Client doesnt send any acknowledgement but ApplicationTest polls    to find if Event is created
Trying to not get into details of other implementation details, let me know if this makes sense to you?

```
class ApplicationTest
    public void checkIfEventCreatedMsgIsSent() {
        Application.createNewEvent("Id101");
        // Wait till the application sends message to the client
        // And then check that the message sent is the correct one
        // if (expectedMessage == recievedMessageFromClient) {
        //   success();
        // }
        int iCount = 0;
        int final MAXCOUNT = 5;
        // Assuming client doesnt send an acknowledgement 
            // but Server pools to find that
        // Below is Polling code method to check if  event is created
        // Servlet context is an example
            // it could be a persistent message on MQ or a value in db
        while(iCount < 5) {
             if (servletcontext.get(msg).get("Id101") == null) {
                 count++;
                 sleep(5000);
             } else { System.out.println("Eureka, msg is sent!")}
        }
    }
class Client{
   public void readMessage(Message message) {
        // Received the new event message with Id101
        // Now this message should be sent to 
            // ApplicationTest.checkIfEventCreatedMsgIsSent and confirmed by it
        // Below msg is a singleton object in Servlet context as an example
            // it could be a persistent message on MQ or a value in db
        // Map<String, Object> msg = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        synchronized(servletContext) {
            servletcontext.get(msg).put("Id101", <object>);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. So we have a Map which pools up all the messages received by the client. And we constantly check (till a timeout) if this message has been sent. Yes, this was my first attempt actually. But the "keys" are not unique. Hence what I could do is, constantly check if the `size of the Map` has increased and once it increases I get the last message which was added and then compare. Is this a right way of approach ?

Comment: 1. Yeap as you feel appropriate - sleep() was just an example to show that you could poll with some delay

2. Since keys are not unique and if you are planning to check based on increase in size, may be you need an ordered collection like ArrayList or Stack where you can pick the top guy based on whether or not you plan to remove it from your collection, you can also add a [EventListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) or if its a Web App they are other Listeners that are available

Answer (score 1):

In observer design pattern , the subject (sender) is never concerned about listeners. If it did this breaks the decoupling between them. Then whats the advantage of Observer pattern !!

Usually , notifications are synchronous calls where the subject iterates through all observer and sends message to each one of them. In your case this might be slow. So you might create multiple threads and send request asynchronously and have acknowledgment as a callback from the sender. Usually in c++ this is achieved using function pointer but you can use anonymous class instead.

Little of code and everything will make sense

```
    public interface Ackowledgement {
        void send();
    }

    class ApplicationTest implements Ackowledgement

    public void checkIfEventCreatedMsgIsSent() {

    Application.createNewEvent("Id101"new Ackowledgement () {
                     public void send()
                     {
                        // no need to wait 
                        // if (expectedMessage == recievedMessageFromClient) {
                        //   success();
                      // });
    }

    class Client

    public void readMessage(Message message,Ackowledgement ack) {
        // Received the new event message with Id101
        // Now this message should be sent to ApplicationTest.checkIfEventCreatedMsgIsSent and confirmed by it
        ack.send();
    }
}
```

If you observe in retrospect, this is like implementing the observer design pattern in reverse way. where subject and observer reverse their roles. Interfaces still preserves decoupling between them.

Comment: Your solution provides me a neat way to do it. But it also demand me to change a lot in the application, which will lead to more complex implementation. So I'll have to go with @KiranHegde's answer. Thank You